# Access the inner most element of a hashmap of type HashMap<Synset, HashSet<Synset>> hyponyms;

Tags: java, loops, hashmap, nested

How can you access the inner most element of the hashmap of the following type? The code I wrote isn't working:

```
                if(!hyponyms.isEmpty()){
                    for(int y = 0; y < hyponyms.size(); y++){
                        System.out.println(hyponyms.get(y).toString());
                    }
                }
```

I want to print out the elements and the above code leads to an error.

Below is what an element the hash-map contains. I just want to print out the text that follows Words:

{[Synset: [Offset: 9286893] [POS: noun] Words: гражданин -- (a native or naturalized member of a state or other political communit)]=[[Synset: [Offset: 9820403] [POS: noun] Words: репатриант -- (a person who has returned to the country of origin or whose citizenship has been restore)], [Synset: [Offset: 10032964] [POS: noun] Words: избиратель -- (a citizen who has a legal right to vot)], [Synset: [Offset: 9764871] [POS: noun] Words: private citizen -- (a citizen who does not hold any official or public positio)], [Synset: [Offset: 9452610] [POS: noun] Words: почётный гражданин города -- (a person who is not a serf or a slav)], [Synset: [Offset: 9145219] [POS: noun] Words: active citizen -- (a citizen who takes an active role in the community (as in crime prevention and neighborhood watch)], [Synset: [Offset: 9287921] [POS: noun] Words: штатский -- (a nonmilitary citize)], [Synset: [Offset: 9984053] [POS: noun] Words: тан -- (a man ranking above an ordinary freeman and below a noble in anglo-saxon england (especially one who gave military service in exchange for land)]]}

Comment: what is the error you get when you run the code?

Comment: I keep getting multiple null pointer exceptions at the place where I get the hash map. But when I run it in debug mode, it goes past that and says the hashmpa does contain a finite number of elements.